# How to "stretch" a melody in Logic Pro X?

Tags: logic-pro

I don't know if "stretching" is the right word but some times I want to add syncopation or experiment with some melody, and always end up moving the individual notes one by one. Is there something to do this automatically, something like a drag and drop feature in Logic Pro X?

For instance, in the image bellow I want the first note on the second bar to land in the first beat of the bar, and all the other notes to the left stretched proportionally so that the whole melody remain the same, although just a bit faster.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using the **MIDI Transform** function in the Piano Roll. Here's a step by step guide to doing this:

- select the region of MIDI notes you want to time stretch and open it in the Piano Roll (as you have done in the picture in your question). Press Cmd-A to select all the notes in that region, or select-drag to select the ones you want to time stretch.
  [image]
- in the toolbar of the Piano Roll window go to Functions->MIDI Transform->Double Speed.
  [image]
- the note you want to move is on beat 5 and you want to move it to beat 4. Therefore, you want to time-stretch by a factor of 5/4, which is 1.25. So, change the value under Position and Div from 2 (for double speed) to 1.25. (You can also set the Length from Div to Thru, so that the note lengths don't change.)
  [image]
- click on Operate Only at the bottom right of the MIDI Transform window and *voila* your notes have been time-stretched!
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way than calculating decimal points in the transformer, although that's a perfectly valid method too.

In Piano Roll, go to Functions and check "Time Handles (command key Ctrl-T). Then lasso (select by dragging an area around) the notes you want stretched or condensed. You should now have a selection with blue tabs on either side, at the top. Grabbing one of the tabs and dragging will then stretch your notes proportionately.

Hope this helps, although this is an old thread.

Comment: This helped me and is similar to the same method used in most other DAWs